# force end text/image block in org-mode html export

Tags: org-mode

I want `foo foo foo ...` to be aligned next to be an image, but for `bar bar bar ...` start a new block of text which is not aligned with `fig.jpg`. Can this be arranged with some special syntax in org-mode?

```
#+ATTR_HTML: height="100" align="left"
[[./img/fig.jpg]] 
foo foo foo ...

bar bar bar ...
```

**Edit**

Just wanted to add that when `bar bar bar ...` is also another section heading, for instance `** Section 2` or something similar, it seems like a new section should not be wrapped with the previous figure by default, but perhaps there is some org-syntax to specify this?

Comment: Are you wanting a caption that is next to the figure, or do you want the whole text to wrap around the figure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon HTML export, the image is wrapped in a `<div class="figure">...</div>` environment.  The org-mode `#+ATTR_HTML:` informatio gets added specifically to the `<img>` tag within the `<div>`.

If you are wanting all of your figures to be "floating" such that the text wraps it, you need to modify the *style* used in the HTML.  This can be done manually in the default style sheet added to the top of the exported HTML file.  A better option is to specify the style you want within the .org file itself.  Something like:

```
#+STYLE: <style type="text/css">
#+STYLE:<!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/
#+STYLE: div.figure { float:left; }
#+STYLE: /*]]>*/-->
#+STYLE: </style>
```

at the beginning of your .org file.  This will set the style of all `<div class="figure">` elements to be floating on the left with text wrapping around on the right hand side.  The following text after the figure will also be wrapped to the right, so you'll want to clear the style with something like a `<br style="clear:both;" />` statement.

[This worg](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/images-and-xhtml-export.html) page has a lot of information about figure placement with captions and word wrapping.  There is more detailed information there.

Comment: Ah, I'd read the worg page but had missed the significance of the `<br style.../>` syntax. This is exactly what I wanted - thanks much!